# How to "sleep" in mainframe COBOL?

Tags: cobol, mainframe, zos

I think I'm using Enterprise COBOL for z/OS.

What's a technique to emulate the functionality of, for example, the standard C library's sleep() function?

Comment: @arunmoezhi - I guess you are not paying for your CUP usage. Somebody must be - and I don't think they would be very happy with this solution!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the easiest method is to use the [Language Environment callable service](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=services-using-language-environment-callable) [CEE3DLY](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=services-cee3dlysuspend-processing-active-enclave-in-seconds) or [CEEDLYM](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=services-ceedlymsuspend-processing-active-enclave-in-milliseconds).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you have found your answer or not.

There is an IBM program that enables the machine to sleep ... or to wait : its name is **ILBOWAT0**.

Here is the link of a very good example on how you can code it : http://www.mvsforums.com/helpboards/viewtopic.php?t=2008&highlight=delay

In this example, WAIT-TIME is in seconds.

Comment: As the ILBO prefix suggests, this is an original COBOL run-time routine included in LE for "backwards compatability". New programs which insist on the need to "wait" should use the CEE*DLY* callable services. Avoid "waiting" like the plague. If infected by it, use the up-to-date routines.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the "sleep" command.
Here's a basic example passing the number of seconds in a variable.

*NOTE: sleep must be in lower case*

```
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
77 WS-SLEEPSECS    PIC S9(2) VALUE 30.

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
 < Miscellaneous Code >

CALL "sleep" USING WS-SLEEPSECS.
```