# how to create delays in cobol program without using any utility?

Tags: db2, delay, cobol, mainframe

I got the code as

```
ACCEPT TIME-TODAY FROM TIME.   

** 10 SECONDS waiting:
PERFORM UNTIL DELTATIME <= 00001000
    ACCEPT TIME-TODAY-2 FROM TIME
    COMPUTE DELTATIME = (TIME-TODAY-2 - TIME-TODAY)
END-PERFORM.
```

Read more: http://ibmmainframes.com/about9953.html#ixzz4NiZIe8cY

but this code is not working for boundary conditions.

Comment: No, this is plain absurd. Do you know the cost of 10 CPU seconds on your Mainframe? I think it would make you feel nauseous. Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: The thread you link to on another web board is ten years old.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786621/how-to-sleep-in-mainframe-cobol

Answer (score 2):

You have the mainframe tag on your question, I'll presume z/OS or z/VM is your operating system.

The runtime routines for your application are collectively called Language Environment.  Whether implicitly or explicitly, you will be calling these runtime routines.  You cannot avoid it.

The runtime includes `CEE3DLY`, which accomplishes your goal.  Check the Language Environment section of the IBM Knowledge Center.

I understand that you believe your requirement is to create a delay in your code without using "any utility."  I am telling you that you are using utilities (the Language Environment runtime routines) all the time in your code.  For example, Working-Storage is allocated by Language Environment routines.  Calling `CEE3DLY` doesn't add any dependencies.

Comment: As this is a duplicate: please don't vote on this answer - @cschneid: please copy most of this answer to the answer you gave in your original answer (duplicate), delete your answer, if possible and vote for duplicate